# Saddle Points in a Linear Stability Analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I'm working on a linear stability analysis and have reached a quadratic that led me to two eigenvalues of opposite signs.
$$\chi s^2 + \bigg [\frac{\chi v^\infty}{d_c} - \frac{\chi\beta}{\zeta} - k + \frac{\tau_c (A_0-A_f^{ss})}{d_c} \bigg ]s + \frac{\beta k}{\zeta}- \frac{k v^\infty}{d_c}$$

Plugging in all the variables led me to two eigenvalues of s $\approx $ 0.0321 and $s\approx -0.001222$

What can I conclude from this? What other analysis can be done to find more information about the stability of my system - Does this saddle point mean it is unstable? I have been changing k as a part of my analysis and get different values but always one positive and one negative.

Comment: You would need to provide more context before this can be answered.

Comment: @copper.hat - What information would need to be provided?

Comment: Stability analysis of what

Comment: @copper.hat - This is a stability analysis of an earthquake fault system.

Comment: I mean is it a second order linear time invariant autonomous ODE? You need to provide some mathematical/control context.

Comment: Here is some context: Essentially I linearized and ended up with two first order linear ODE's (shown below:)$$\left( \frac{\sigma a}{v^\infty} + \frac{G}{2v_s} \right) \Delta \dot{v} = -\tau_c \Delta \dot{A_f} + k\Delta v$$ and $$\Delta\dot A_f=\frac{n\zeta}{t_c}(1-\frac{1}{n})(\frac{A_f^{ss}-A_0}{\zeta})^{\frac{-1}{n}}(\frac{\Delta A_f}{\zeta})-\frac{v^\infty}{d_c}\Delta A_f-\frac{A_f^{ss}}{d_c}\Delta v+\frac{A_0}{d_c}\Delta v$$ which I then proposed general solutions like $$\Delta v = Ve^{st}$$ then substituted and solved, yielding the quadratic. All var. values in the quad. are known